# How to use Cron job to delay variables that will be posted into the Database for some minute

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, cron

I have a form in my laravel script, I want to know how to use cron job to delay the form once it is submitted. I want it to make it submit to the database after Five minutes.

Here is the HTML code to the form, I want it to post to the cron jobs first before it is sent to the database after 5 minutes.

```
<html>
    <form method="post" action="{{action('SomeController@withdrawal')}}">
    <!--............................... collapse one -->
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-{{$bgmenu}}" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <div class="span-icon">
                <div class="fa fa-clone">   Trade</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="span-mode"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body bg-{{$bg}} shadow">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="text-{{$text}}">Symbol</h5>
                    <select type="text" id="symbol" name="symbol"  placeholder="Symbol" required>
                        <option value="BCH/BTC">BCH/BTC</option>
                        <option value="XLM/USD">XLM/USD</option>
                        <option value="XRP/BTC">XRP/BTC</option>
                        <option value="XRP/EUR">XRP/EUR</option>
                        <option value="XRP/USD">XRP/USD</option>
                        <option value="ZEC/BTC">ZEC/BTC</option>
                        <option value="ZRX/BTC">ZRX/BTC</option>
                        <option value="ZRX/EUR">ZRX/EUR</option>
                        <option value="ZRX/USD">ZRX/USD</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="text-{{$text}}">Interval</h5>
                    <select type="text" id="time" name="time" value="{{Auth::user()->intv}}"  class="form-control  text-{{$text}} bg-{{$bg}}" placeholder="Interval" required>
            
                        <option value="1-Minute">1 min</option>
                        <option value="3-Minutes">3 min</option>
                        <option value="5-Minutes">5 min</option>
                        <option value="15-Minutes">15 min</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="text-{{$text}}">Amount</h5>
                    <input type="text" value="{{Auth::user()->buy}}"  class="form-control text-{{$text}} bg-{{$bg}}" placeholder="100.00" name="amount" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 class="text-{{$text}}">Strike Rate</h5>
                    <select type="text" id="trade" name="trade"   class="form-control  text-{{$text}} bg-{{$bg}}" placeholder="Interval" required>
                        <option>Choose One....</option>             
                        <option value="High_Sell">High Sell</option>
                        <option value="Highest_Sell">Highest Sell</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the use case? Why not insert the data and set a date+5min in the dataset?

Comment: Save the form submit into a 'temp' database table, then have a php script that runs via cron to check that temp database table and move any data from it that is due for moving

Comment: Instead use `queue worker` for this task. Dispatch form data to the queue and process it with a delay of 5 minutes.

Comment: Can you explain more please i dont know how to go about it

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement, and potentially an XY problem where the real way to achieve what you actually need is to do something else entirely. Why exactly do you need this delay?

Comment: i don't want the user to see the data inputted until its 5 minutes, there is table for the user where  this transactions shows, But i dont want it to show until the required time.

Comment: So just make that page for the user run a query which excludes all results submitted less than 5 minutes ago. Much simpler.